# Monitoring for certain incoming emails from iphone app

Tags: iphone, monitoring, email

I will try to develop a library for apps that check incoming emails only from one certain domain. What I want is scan the inbox of mail.app for a email coming from me@minedomain.com and only from that domain. Is it any possibilities where I can access the iphone inbox database or something where I can make a search and put the correct incoming email and attach to some view in my app?

I know that exist kind of different solution where you can scan your Gmail, like how TripIt does it on the app, account but I also need to scan any email account.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't not access the mail.app or any other app for that mater.

It might work on a jailbroken iPhone, but definitely not using the offical SDK.

Comment: @rckoenes Could you tell me how products such as mobile-spy.com/monitoring_features.html#top monitor email activity? Do they not access the Mail App.

Comment: @HellsGuardian there software is only available in jailbroken device: http://www.mobile-spy.com/compatibility.html#version

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks very much!